# Question about norms $p$ and $q$.

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I have a simply question:

Show that if $x,y \in \mathbb{R^n}$, then $$\biggr|\sum{x_jy_j}\biggr|\leq \| x \|_p \| y \|_q$$

First, I proved that, if $s,t\geq 0$, then $$st\leq\dfrac{s^p}{p}+\dfrac{t^q}{q}$$
And, I think make a change of variable, $s=|x_j|$ and $t=|y_j|$, but I do not get to see if it's okay. Or maybe exist another form, regards

Comment: This is known as Hölder's inequality. Note that we need $p,q\in[0,\infty]$ with $\frac1p+\frac1q=1$ (where $\frac1\infty$ is defined as zero) for this to hold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose here that $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1$.

Somehow, the $\frac{1}{p}$ and $\frac{1}{q}$ terms are annoying, so you want to get rid of them knowing that the sum of the inverse is $1$.

> You're almost there, try using $s = \frac{x_i}{(\sum x_i^p)^{1/p}}$

Comment: this is most probably a duplicate right?...